# How to insert a column into a DataFrame without generating the SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chained-assignment

I would like to insert a column into an existing DataFrame. Ideally without copying existing data. Whatever I try, later assignments to the resulting DataFrame generate a SettingWithCopyWarning, if the inserted data contains null values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1]})
df = df.assign(b=pd.Series(data=pd.NaT, index=df.index))
df['a'].iloc[0] = 5
```

Replacing `assign` with either of

```
df['b'] = pd.Series(data=pd.NaT, index=df.index)
df.insert(column='b', loc=0, value=pd.NaT)
```

results in the same warning.

Strange enough, if the inserted value is not null (replacing pd.NaT with, e.g., 0) doesn't generate a warning. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be with `df['a'].iloc[0] = 5`, where you're using [chained assignment](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).  Try this instead:

```
df.at[0, 'a'] = 5
# Or: df.loc[0, 'a'] = 5, but `.at` is preferred when assigning scalar
```

Comment: Strange enough, the warning is not generated if I replace the null value with a non-null value. That is why I assumed that this chained assignment should work fine. Also, I would like to use position-based selection for rows and label-based selection for columns, which does not work with `at`, `loc`, `iat`, or `iloc`, AFAIK. and the `ix` is deprecated.

Comment: @Konstantin, for mixed (position + label) indexing use: `df.loc[df.index[position], 'column_name']`

Comment: Yeah, regarding `.ix` and combining position/label-based indexing: it might seem inconvenient, but `.ix` was deprecated _specifically for that reason_.  The developers wanted to avoid ambiguity where possible--for example, if your index was [1, 0] and you used `.ix`, should this refer to a position or label?

Comment: @MaxU: Yes, I was aware of that possibility but found it ugly. `df[column_name].iloc[position]` is much more intuitive. But seems that `df.loc[df.index[position], 'column_name']` is the only way to avoid the warning.